# Gravity in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, gravity

So im making a flappy bird like game in javascript because my friends requested I do so and I have a squid that needs to be affected by gravity and right now im just setting an interval for it to go down how could I create gravity for my squid.
(x and y are the squids positions)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //THIS IS PROTOTYPE VERSION 1.0 CREATE NEW FILE AND REVISE BEFORE FINAL COPY


    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var squid = new Image();
    squid.src = "squid.png";

    var x = 15;
    var y = 10;

    setInterval(Main, 1000/60);

    function Main() {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,1000)
        ctx.drawImage(squid,x,y)
        y+= 1;


    }

    function jump() {
        y -= 20;


    }

    function moveForward() {
        x += 5;

    }

    document.onkeydown = function (e) {
            if(e.which == 32){
                    jump();
            }

            if (e.which == ) {
                moveForward();
            }
    }

</script>
```

Thats my whole code please comment down below what to do
Thanks.

Comment: What to do: ask a question.

Comment: Laws of physics for an object state, roughly speaking, how its coordinates and *velocity* in the "next moment" are calculated from coordinates and velocity in "previous moment". To emulate them, you need to track object velocity (with another two variables, ``vx`` and ``vy``). For example: ``x=x+vx*dt; y=y+vy*dt; vy=a*vy-g*dt; vx=a*vx; ``, where ``a`` emulates air friction, ``dt`` is time between recalculations and ``g`` is gravitational force. Jumps and moves increase speed, not coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should think a little more carefully about what you want to achieve. Rather than just posting this question and expecting others to do your coding for you, do a little research, try some different things and then if you're still stuck, come back and ask something a little more specific.

As a starting point, you could try using the acceleration due to gravity that we experience on the earth's surface (9.8ms<sup>-2</sup>), though you'd probably have to adjust this to fit with your unit of measurement.